# How to implement such control as in the game: rolly vortex?

Tags: unity-game-engine

How to implement such control as on video? Game: rolly vortex
Video - https://youtu.be/sShnjs6D59M
How to achieve such control? What should I use? help me please

My code (edited):

```
public class TouchControl : MonoBehaviour {

    float level_width = 1f;
    float speed = 0.01f;

    void Update()
    {
        if(Input.touchCount > 0)
        {
            Debug.Log("Result = " + ((Input.GetTouch(0).position.x / Screen.width) - 0.5f) * 2);
            if(((Input.GetTouch(0).position.x / Screen.width) - 0.5f) * 2 > 0) {
                Debug.Log(((Input.GetTouch(0).position.x + 0.5f) / 2) + "  result");
                MoveLeft();
            }
            if (((Input.GetTouch(0).position.x / Screen.width) - 0.5f) * 2 < 0)
            {
                Debug.Log(((Input.GetTouch(0).position.x + 0.5f) / 2) + "  result");
                MoveRight();
            }
        }
    }

    void MoveLeft()
    {
        Vector3 newPos = transform.position;
        newPos.x = (Input.GetTouch(0).position.x * level_width) * - 1;
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, newPos, speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    void MoveRight()
    {
        Vector3 newPos = transform.position;
        newPos.x = Input.GetTouch(0).position.x * level_width;
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, newPos, speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should get you started:

```
public float level_width = 5f;
public float speed = 0.1f; // 0..1

if(Input.touchCount > 0)
{
    Vector3 newPos = transform.position;
    newPos.x =  Input.GetTouch(0).position.x * width;
    transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, newPos, speed * Time.deltaTime)
 }
```

`speed` will adjust the time it takes for the ball to reach the touch position.

`level_width` helps to scale the input from screen coordinates to your world/level.

Edit: I simplified your code a bit:

```
public class TouchControl: MonoBehaviour {

    float level_width = 10f;
    float speed = 0.01 f;
    float target_xpos = 0f;

    void Update() {
        if (Input.touchCount > 0) {
            target_xpos = ((Input.GetTouch(0).position.x / Screen.width) - 0.5 f) * 2 * level_width;


            MoveToFinger();
        }
    }

    void MoveToFinger() {

        Vector3 newPos = transform.position;
        newPos.x = target_xpos;
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, newPos, speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }



}
```

Comment: yes, Vector3 can't assign 2 arguments and i changed from Vector3 to Vector2. Another issue: movement of an object is very fast, he moves from 0 x coordinate to 150x in one tap, it's too fast

Comment: Sorry, forgot the time argument in Lerp. Will edit post.

Comment: hello Kyler! Now my gameobject is moving in one direction :( He moves to the right (+) by x coordinate. He can't move left (-) by x coordinate. What i have to do?

Comment: Input.GetTouch(0).position.x is between 0 and 1. Just use `(Input.GetTouch(0).position.x + 0.5f) / 2f)` - this will convert it to -1..1 - then it should work :)

Comment: (Input.GetTouch(0).position.x + 0.5f) / 2) returns a big value like 110.4f, 116f, 133f e.t.c this functions isn't returns -1 or 1

Comment: Looks like touch position is in screen pixels. So convert like this:

`((Input.GetTouch(0).position.x / Screen.width) - 0.5f) * 2f)`

Comment: it works! but to the right side my gameobject moves very slowly then to the left side. Debug.log to the left side returns more greater value then to the right. Example: to the left side: 205, to the right: 42. How can i fix it?

Comment: i've updated my topic. i've added my code, look at my code pls

Comment: I simplified your code and cleaned it up. MoveLeft and MoveRight are now simply "MoveToFinger" :)

Comment: i copied your code, but my gameobject isn't moving, value of targetxpos is between -1 and 1. Screenshot of logs - http://joxi.ru/p27OjJEUK3bEb2

Comment: I added `* level_width` but that may need to be a greater number. However you may want to make sure `speed` is 0.5 or 1 for testing. (set in inspector, not in code, this will be ignored for public variables)